# Is there a way to use CGAL to perform adaptive remeshing

Tags: cgal

Suppose I have a highly refined mesh, which can be achieved by using using the remeshing code in CGAL.

PMP::isotropic_remeshing(
      faces(mesh),
      target_edge_length,
      mesh,
      PMP::parameters::number_of_iterations(nb_iter)
      .protect_constraints(true)//i.e. protect border, here
      );

Now if I want to use the edge collapse function in CGAL to selectively only collapse areas that I wanted to using this function,

int r = edge_collapse(surface_mesh
                     ,stop_predicate
                     ,vertex_index_map(vimap)
                       .edge_index_map(eimap)
                       .edge_is_border_map(ebmap)
                       .get_cost(cf)
                       .get_placement(pf)
                       .visitor(vis)
                     );

I understand that there is a "get_cost(cf)" where i could increase the costing in one region of the mesh, so as to lower the number of edge collapse in that region.

Could anyone show me how to do that?

Specifically, suppose I have a sphere of size 1, with an isotropic mesh of edge length 0.001. I wanted a gradually grading of edge length to go from 0.01 on one end to 0.1 on the other opposite side of the sphere. How do i achieve it with the two functions?

q